# Elementor preview is not the same as online version

Tags: wordpress, migration, elementor

I'm a newbie

After migration (local) wordpress synology to hostinger.

After migration I have question.
Some posts from the blog were in wrong format.

By performing a workaround it worked fine again (open in elementor, make a minor change and upload)

but....
https://eulinkonline.nl/brunsveldwal-wandeling-slangenburg/
I cannot get it live in correct layout, while Elementor preview does have the correct layout

I did clear my cache with lite speed cache plugin
and no conflicts given in plugins (section in wordpress)

It has to be like this:
https://eulinkonline.nl/trage-tocht-ommerschans/

[Wrong format:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOjRa.jpg)
[Good format:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pcfF.png)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.